# Using a reference to CFPropertyListRef in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, pointers, reference, core-foundation

I'm currently converting some Objective-C code to swift and I am stuck.
I do have an internal API which fills a CFPropertyList and give back it's format.

```
MyFunction(CFPropertyListRef list, CFPropertyListFormat *fmt);
```

In Objective-C I'm calling it via

```
CFDictionaryRef myList;
CFPropertyListFormat fmt;
MyFunction(&myList, &fmt)
```

Via the "Generated Interface" i can see that swift converted to

```
MyFunction(_ list: CFPropertyList!, _ fmt: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFPropertyListFormat>))
```

When I'm trying to call the function in swift via

```
var fmt = CFPropertyListFormat.XMLFormat_v1_0
var plist = NSDictionary() as CFPropertyListRef
MyFunction(plist, &fmt)
```

I'm getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS.
As the compiler doesn't complain about the types I think this should be right.
Any help is very appreciated!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your usage in Objective-C is really right, the function header of your `MyFunction` needs to be something like this:

```
extern void MyFunction(CFPropertyListRef *list, CFPropertyListFormat *fmt);
```

(`CFPropertyListRef` actually is just a typealias of `void *` in Objective-C/C. So, the compiler rarely outputs warnings for many possible type mis-uses.)

And Swift 2 imports such function as:

```
public func MyFunction(list: UnsafeMutablePointer<Unmanaged<CFPropertyList>?>, _ fmt: UnsafeMutablePointer<CFPropertyListFormat>)
```

So, assuming you have changed the function header as above,
you need to use it as follows:

```
var fmt: CFPropertyListFormat = .XMLFormat_v1_0
var umPlist: Unmanaged<CFPropertyList>? = nil
MyFunction(&umPlist, &fmt)
var plist = umPlist?.takeRetainedValue() //or this may be `umPlist?.takeUnretainedValue()`
```